# EBCDIC to UTF-8 encoding

Tags: xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, ebcdic

I need an advice.

I retrieve a string from a cobol routine  that should contain the German "`ü`" but the `EBCDIC` encode it as "`è`" . When the string is passed to that has to   xml the UTF-8 encode it as `#252#` instead of the "`ü`".  Can someone help me on understand how pass the correct value to xml in UTF-8?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMGV_3.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfhp3/dqx1dfhp3i2.htm ?

Comment: Character encodings encode text to bytes and decode bytes to text. So, when you say EBCDIC encode it as "è", you're already going sideways.

Comment: You have a simple input code page specification error. Please tell us what programming language/operating system you are using where you see "è" instead of "ü", so we can give further advice. You need to specify your incoming EBCDIC code page as 1141(https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp_cpgid.html), where "ü" is defined at 0xd0. Since you are receiving "è", your incoming code page is specified as either French (CP 1147) or Italian (CP 1144), which have that character at 0xd0.